# Alpaca "if filled"

Tags: json, forms, conditional-statements

I'm working with Alpaca to render forms from JSON.
I'm loading data into the form using the data option of Alpaca.

In my schema I need that any field of 3 be filled :

```
"anyOf": [
            {
            "required": [
                "addr.ipv4"
            ]
            },
            {
            "required": [
                "addr.ipv6"
            ]
            },
            {
            "required": [
                "addr.hardware.mac"
            ]
            }
        ]
```

What I would like to do :

When I load my data, if any of the 3 required field is already filled, make it readonly. If not filled, don't make it readonly.